# Linear Related Message Attack on RSA

Tags: rsa, linear-cryptanalysis

I have a question about this attack: Oded Yacobi and Yacov Yacobi, [*A New Related Message Attack on RSA*](https://www.iacr.org/archive/pkc2005/33860001/33860001.pdf) (in [proceedings of PKCS2005](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-30580-4_1)).

Given $e$ linear related messages encrypted with RSA:
$c_i = ({x_i}^e \bmod N)$

where, $x_i = a_i*x + b_i$,

the author claims that given the $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s values, it is possible to obtain the original message $m$. He shows that for the case of $x_i = x + b$, but I can't see how is the general form to apply this attack for messages $x_i = a_i*x + b_i$.

More specifically, I'm having difficulties in calculating the $p_k$ values presented in section 2.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ability to recover $x$ in the latter case is a direct consequence of RSA's homomorphic property and the ability to recover $x$ in the former case.

Suppose you are given the equations (with $c_i,a_i,b_i$ known):

$$c_i=(a_i\cdot x+b_i)^e\bmod N$$
$$\iff c_i=(a_i\cdot x+a_i\cdot b_i\cdot a_i^{-1})^e\bmod N$$
$$\iff c_i=a^e_i(x+b_i\cdot a_i^{-1})^e\bmod N$$
$$\iff c_i\cdot a^{-e}_i =(x+b_i\cdot a_i^{-1})^e\bmod N$$
$$\iff c_i' =(x+b'_i)^e\bmod N$$

With $b_i':=b_i\cdot a_i^{-1}$ and $c_i':=c_i\cdot a^{-e}_i$ which both only depend on known quantities, as you can always find multiplicative inverse $\bmod N$ (or if you can't in one instance, you can factor $N$) and you know $e,c_i,a_i,b_i$.

So you can use the ability to recover $y$ from $g_i=(y+f_i)^e\bmod N$ to recover (using the above equations) $x$ from $c_i=(a_i\cdot x+b_i)^e\bmod N$.

Comment: That is right. Thank you. I wonder if there is a way to compute that when the public keys have the same exponent but different modulo (e, Ni).